# Does $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}}{\frac{n}{2^n}}$ have two answers?

Tags: calculus, limits

> Does $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}}{\frac{n}{2^n}}$ or the equivalent, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}} \cdot\frac{2^n}{n})$ have two answers?

Honestly, this might be a dumb question to ask, and it might be an arithmetic error, but this is how I got the two different answers:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}} \cdot\frac{2^n}{n}) \implies  \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)  \cdot 2^n}{2^n  \cdot2n} \quad \because \quad2^{n+1}=2 \cdot2^n $$

Now, the  two answers results from choosing to multiply out $(n+1) \cdot 2^n$ which is $n2^n+2^n$ and choosing to leave it.

Let's start with the second case first: If we leave $(n+1) \cdot2^n$ as it is, then cancel the $2^n$ on top and on bottom, leaving the limit of $\frac{n+1}{2n}$, as x approaches infinity, which is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$. Therefore the second case implies if we multiply out $(n+1) \cdot2^n$ which is $n2^n+2^n$, then we get $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{n2^n+2^n}{n2^n  \cdot 2n})$. Thus we can cancel out $2^n$ from all the terms, leaving $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{n+1}{n  \cdot 2n}) \implies \lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{n+1}{2n^2})$ which is a different limit, and equals to $0$.

So does this limit have two answers? Is there an algebraic error?

Comment: All those $\implies$ signs are wrong! It means "implies", and is a verb.

Comment: Sorry, Tony. I am new to Latex, and also pretty new to advance mathematics itself. Do you have a suggestion for next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra $n$ in the denominator that came out of nowhere.

Comment: I multiplied $2^{n+1}$ by n. I can't find where I had went wrong?

Comment: While expanding the numerator you should leave the denominator untouched, and $2^{n+1} \cdot n=2^n \cdot 2n$ as it is in the oter case.

Comment: Oh Thank you. I see where I went wrong. I spent nearly an hour on this for a stupid mistake. I added an extra n because I had mistaken $2^{n+1}$ for $2^n+2$ and distributed. I just replaced that addition operator with a multiplication operator. I'm so sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 4):

Limits (if they exist) are unique, so there cannot be two answers. It looks like the mistake is that in your second case, you accidentally introduced an extra factor of $n$ in the denominator. You made it $\color{red}{n}2^n\cdot 2n$, whereas it should just be $2^n \cdot 2n$.

Comment: I multiplied $2^{n+1}$ by n. I can't find where I had went wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't be multiplying by $n$ in the denominator. Did you think you should do this because you were expanding $(n+1)2^n$ in the numerator?

Comment: I was just trying another way by multiplying them all out. In other words, I was just multiplying the fractions. I'm sorry if its something so trivial I overlooked. :(

Comment: You already correctly multiplied the fractions at the start (the result was $\frac{(n+1)2^n}{2^n\cdot 2n}$). If you want to expand the numerator now, you can do this, but the denominator will be unchanged, i.e. you would get $\frac{n2^n+2^n}{2^n\cdot 2n}$.

Comment: I found the mistake. It was very trivial, and a small multiplication mistake. I'm so sorry for the inconvenience. Thank you.